# Typescript tsc -w command not watching for file changes

Tags: typescript, angular

I am currently trying to configure my application to watch for any file changes in Typescript and then recompile and restart the server when this happens. Here is my tsconfig.json:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "ES5",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "removeComments": false,
    "noImplicitAny": false,
    "rootDir" : "assets/app",
    "outDir": "../public/js/app"
  },
  "files": [
    "./assets/app/*"
  ],
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules"
  ],
  "atom": {
    "rewriteTsconfig": true
  }
}
```

As you can see, I have set the rootDir (where the .ts files are kept) and set the output directory (where there transpiled code is stored).

Here is my file structure:

[image]

Now, when I try and run the tsc -w command I get the following error:

```
error TS6053: File 'assets/app/*.ts' not found.
```

Which would indicate that the tsconfig.json file is not properly parsing my ts files from within the rootDir folder properly. I have tried changing this but nothing seems to work. Does anyone have any ideas?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure how it is with the atom editor, because they have some different settings, but as far as i know, you cannot use `files` with `exclude`. Because you already point to the `rootDir`, the `files` option is redundant, and should be removed

Comment: Hi, that seems to get my watcher running but I have now encountered another error. I get lots and lots of these and the code does not get transpiled:public/js/vendor/@angular/router/esm/src/facade/exceptions.d.ts(22,27): error TS1005: ';' expected.
public/js/vendor/@angular/router/esm/src/facade/exceptions.d.ts(23,14): error TS1005: '=' expected.
public/js/vendor/@angular/router/esm/src/facade/exceptions.d.ts(23,21): error TS1005: ';' expected.

Comment: you should add the `public/js/vendor` directory to your `exclude` as well